# Equating emissions to mass loading

Tags: experimental-chemistry, atmospheric-chemistry

I want to estimate aerosol mass loading by dividing emissions of the particular aerosol by the associated area. Assuming the air had no other particles in it to begin with - is this procedurally correct?

Comment: Could you describe your system a little more thoroughly?  When you say "associated area" do you mean volume or the area of some surface on which the aerosol is depositing.  There will be suggestions that this is off-topic as not being about chemistry.  What is the composition of the particles and what type of surface is your chamber, container, etc.?  Humidity can lead to increased aerosol mass; what kind of water vapor concentrations are present in your system.  My questions are too much to answer in comments, I'm suggesting you re-phrase your description and question.

Answer (score 1):

Given the context of your question, I assume you must mean "the associated *volume*", not "the associated *area*".

Other than that, you are exactly correct.  For example, given the following parameters:

> aerosol emissions rate = 0.010 mg $\mathrm{hr^{-1}}$
>   duration of aerosol emissions = 1 $\mathrm{hr}$
>   container volume = 1 $\mathrm{m{^3}}$

Then the aerosol mass loading would be given as:

> total aerosol mass = 0.010 mg $\mathrm{hr^{-1}}$ $\mathrm{x}$ 1
>   $\mathrm{hr}$ = 0.010 mg
>
> **aerosol mass loading = 0.010 mg / 1 $\mathrm{m{^3}}$ = 0.010 mg
>   $\mathrm{m{^{-3}}}$**

If you really meant *area* and not *volume*, as in surface area of the aerosols, then your statement would be over-simplified and you would need to include other assumptions made concerning particle size and density etc. in order to determine whether the way your statement is correct as written.